# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password') NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

When I try to use an invalid email address in the login form, the app crashes saying: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'password').

You can see my **auth.js**'s login part below:

```js
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;

        if ( !email || !password ) {
            return res.status(400).render('login', {
                message: 'Please provide an email and password.'
            })
        }

        db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
            console.log(results);
            if( !results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password) ) ) {
                res.status(401).render('login', {
                    message: 'Email or password is incorrect.'
                })
            } else {
                const id = results[0].id;

                const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                });

                console.log('The token is: ' + token);

                const cookieOptions = {
                    expires: new Date(
                        Date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                    ),
                    httpOnly: true
                }

                res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
                res.status(200).redirect("/");
            }
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

It should show the same line that I can see when I use an incorrect password (That part works just fine).

`message: 'Email or password is incorrect.'`

Comment: Change `!results` to `results.length == 0`. An empty array is truthy in JavaScript.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to read `password` field of the first query result, but the result does not exist. You have a check for `results`, but I assume it returns an array of queried results. But in your case, it seems like there are no actual records matching the query, so the array is empty, therefore your test condition will always be true. You should add check for `results[0]` or `results.length` to see if there is a user with such email and if not, respond with 404 response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email is invalid, the query will return an empty array, not an `undefined`, meaning that your check is wrong - you should check the length of the array.

Of course, you can always leave the check that `result` is defined just to be on the safe side:

```
if( !results || !results.length || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password) ) ) {
    res.status(401).render('login', {
        message: 'Email or password is incorrect.'
    });
} else {
```